# Can DBA create a public synonym for a table that has the same name as an existing table

Tags: oracle, query, syntax

Suppose a DBA created a public synonym for a table and named it `hr`. The user also created a table with the same name `hr`.

If a user performs a query like the following statement:

```
select * from hr;
```

What will be returned by the query?

Whose table values will be shown?

- The records of the public synonym
- The records of the table

Answer (score 4):

The user table will take precedence over the public synonym.
The data from the user table would be shown.

Oracle's object name resolution is explained in the article [Managing Object Name Resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/general008.htm#ADMIN11561) (*Oracle Database Administrators Guide*)

The following SQL code will explain the use case:

```
SQL> conn user1
Enter password:
Connected.

SQL> create table test as select * from user_objects where 1=2; --Creating first table with 0 rows 
Table created.

SQL> create table conflicting_name as select * from user_objects where rownum<2; --Creating second table with 1 row
Table created.

SQL> select count(0) from test; --first table with 0 rows 
  COUNT(0)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(0) from conflicting_name; --second table with 1 row
  COUNT(0)
----------
         1
```

At this stage you have the `test` table containing zero (0) rows and the `conflicting_name` table containing one (1) row.

Let's continue by creating a public synonym and querying `conflicting_name`:

```
SQL>  create public synonym conflicting_name for test; --public synonym with second table's name for first table
Synonym created.


SQL> select count(0) from conflicting_name; --second table still points to original table and public synonym not used 
  COUNT(0)
----------
         1
```

The result shows you that the query is run against the table `conflicting_name` which contains one row and not against the public synonym `conflicting_name` which references the `test` table containing zero rows.

What happens with a different user? Let's try:

```
SQL> conn user2 
Enter password:
Connected.

SQL> -- Connected to different user 

SQL> select count(0) from conflicting_name; --now public synonym pointing to first table kicks in 
  COUNT(0)
----------
         0

SQL> select count(0) from user1.conflicting_name; --can explicitely access original table bypassing public synonym 
  COUNT(0)
----------
         1
```

Because of the public synonym, user2 will be querying the `test` table. Only if user2 directly queries the `user1.conflicting_name` table will the single row be returned.